# How to play animation on div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Here is my script so far:

Html:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Css:

```
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

/* Here is the animation (keyframes) */
@keyframes fading {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

But how do i get the css animation (keyframes) to play on the div #test using some javascript?

Comment: Assign your `@keyframes fading` to a class and use JavaScript to add/remove the class as needed - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Here a [tuto link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: Why would you link w3fools if there is a billion professional sites and original documentation....

Comment: read more about animation here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp

Comment: If you get the right answer apply it clicking in the check button.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add 'animation' css property from js:

```
document.getElementById('test').style.animation = 'fading 2s infinite'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the animation to a class in CSS.

```
.fade {
    animation: fading 1s forwards; // "fading" is the keyframe animation you created
}
```

`[forwards][1]` makes it so the element remains in the final state of the animation.

Then in Javascript when you want to animate your div, add the class to the element.

```
var el = document.getElementById('test'); // get a reference to the targeted element
el.classList.add('fade'); // add the class name to that element
```

```js
document.getElementById('fader').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('test');
  el.classList.add('fade');
});
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fade {
  animation: fading 1s forwards;
}


/* Here is the animation (keyframes) */

@keyframes fading {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>

<button type="button" id="fader">fade out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.cube {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background:#000;
  
  animation:spin 3s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cube"><div>
```

Like this give youre animation name like me(spin) and use this variable in animation selector with css. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the animation keyframe `fading` to the `div`.
Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_keyframes2)

```css
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: fading 5s infinite;
    animation: fading 5s infinite;
}

/* Here is the animation (keyframes) */
@keyframes fading {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just declared the animation and did not used. You have to call it with "animation" keyword:

```
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation: fading 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JS when you use @keyframes css

To add the @keyframes faded animation to the div just add those additional 2 lines to #test css . This will create 5s animation

```
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: fading 5s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: fading 5s;
}
```

You can add 'infinite' to loop the animation

```
-webkit-animation: fading 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation: fading 5s infinite;
```